# PHP assignment return value

Tags: php, syntax-error

Assuming that you can do `(new Object)->method()` in PHP5.4+ I was wondering why I cannot do this:

```
<?php

class Item {
    public $property = 'test';
}

class Container
{
    public function getItem()
    {
        return new Item();
    }
}

echo get_class(($object = (new Container())->getItem())); // returns Item

// this comes up with error
echo ($object = (new Container())->getItem())->property;
```

Why the last line of code triggers `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`

Edit:

It looks like I need to clarify my question, as I see answers completely not related to my question. I'm not asking how to get rid of syntax error. My question is:
Why I cannot access property on expression `($object = (new Container())->getItem())`, while `get_class()` tells me that this is an instance of Item?

Comment: Even if it's possible, why do you want to ?

Comment: And what about this: `echo (new Container())->getItem()->property;` ??? Or to make it working with Your assingment: `echo $property = (new Container())->getItem()->property;`

Comment: @HamZa I don't want to do, I just wonder why get_class tells me that I have an object of class Item, but I cannot access its property.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only dereference function return values in PHP 5.4 (I believe in 5.5 you can dereference newly-created arrays like `['x','y','z'][$index]`)

Since assignment is not a function, you can't dereference it.

Comment: Can you provide more details please? According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php): _The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3._ Which I presume the value of `($object = (new Container())->getItem())` is equivalent to `$object`. This is what `get_class` says.

Comment: Dereferencing is a special syntax, which takes place during the parsing phase (before ANY code is executed). The parser cannot "see" that the assignment is something that can be dereferenced, because that depends on things that happen at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an extended class?

```
class Item {
 public $Val = "Testing";

}

class Container extends Item {

    public function getItem()
    {
        return new Item();
    } // This method is no longer needed

}


$Object = new Container();
echo $Object->Val; // Output of: Testing
```

This has been available since PHP4

[Manual For Extends](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)

Or if you wish to initialize the object from OOP Scope:

```
Class Item { 
 public $Val = "SomeString"; 
}

class Container { 
 public $Instance;
 public function __construct(){
   $this->Instance = new Item();
 } 

}
$Object = new Container();
echo $Object->Instance->Val;
```